# Using JavaScript "Regular Expression" in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript

I want to check password strength of password entered by user in Asp.Net page.
I have comeup with a javascript regular expression to do it.
But I am not sure How to match string using regular expression. I have write this code, but its not working.

I think there is an error in line

```
   if (true==checkspace.exec(password))
   alert("spaces are not allowed");
```

Comment: How to check for white spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [JavaScript Regular Expression object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions)

it looks like you want [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), as you expect a boolean to be returned, depending on if the pattern is found in the string

```
regularExpression.test("my string to test");
```

Comment: `/\s/g.test("my string to test");` will return true if the string contains a whitespace

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to test that a password is at least 6 characters long and contains at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter and at least one digit you could use this:

```
var passwordRegex = /^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W]).*$/;
var password = 'adg6htyA';
var isPasswordStrong = passwordRegex.test(password);
alert(isPasswordStrong); // shows true
```